# Goldendict and spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

i want to use spacy it in programs tab in goldendict to Tokenization and Lemmatization of searched sentence "%GDSEARCH%"

i downloaded spacy with

pip install -U pip setuptools wheel
pip install -U spacy
python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm

and made a virtual environment

F:\HAMO\Languages\Files\GoldenDict-NG\sentence-split\venv\sentencesplitter\Scripts\python

but i don't know the command line to type it after python

i expect it to split the searched sentence into origin words